# How to create column based on previous rows?

Tags: sql, window-functions, presto

I have the following table:

```
id  type
1   NULL
2    A
3   NULL
4   NULL
5    A
6   NULL
7    B
8    A
9    B
10   NULL
```

I want to create a column where each row takes the current status if exist if not take the status from the previous one.
Basically want to get this:

```
id  type   new_type
1   NULL    NULL   -- firs one no previous so it can only be null
2    A       A     -- current type A so take it
3   NULL     A     -- no type so take the new_type of previous
4   NULL     A
5    A       A
6   NULL     A
7    B       B
8    A       A
9    B       B
10   NULL    B
```

I know I need window function here but I don't know how a window function can reference a column that is "in progress" basically the window function need to reference both `type` and `new_type` but `new_type` doesn't exist yet.. it's the output.

How can this be done in SQL / Presto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can this be done in SQL

For example, it can be

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.type,
       ( SELECT t2.type
         FROM sourcetable t2
         WHERE t2.id <= t1.id
           AND t2.type IS NOT NULL
         ORDER BY id DESC
         LIMIT 1 ) new_type
FROM sourcetable t1
```

Answer (score 2):

Presto has comprehensive support for window functions. Here, you can use `lag()` with the `ignore nulls` option to replace `null` values in column `type`:

```
select 
    id,
    type,
    coalesce(
        type,
        lag(type ignore nulls) over(order by id)
    ) new_type
from mytable
```

Answer (score 2):

Needs a cursor, especially if the id is not guarantee to be sequential and without gaps.

This will run in MS-SQL:

```html
-- stage sample data
drop table if exists oldTable
create table oldTable (id int, old_type nvarchar(1))
go
insert into oldTable values (1, null), (2, 'A'), (3, null), (4, null), (5, 'A'), (6, null), (7, 'B'), (8, 'A'), (9, 'B'), (10, null)
go

-- get new table ready
drop table if exists newTable
create table newTable (
 id int,
 old_type nvarchar(1),
 new_type nvarchar(1)
)
GO

-- prepare for lots of cursing
declare @the_id int
declare @the_type nvarchar(1)
declare @running_type nvarchar(1)
declare mycursor cursor for
 select
  id, old_type
 from
  oldTable

-- do a barrel roll
open mycursor
fetch mycursor into @the_id, @the_type
while @@ERROR = 0 and @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
 set @running_type = COALESCE(@the_type, @running_type)
 
 insert into newTable(id, old_type, new_type)
 values (@the_id, @the_type, @running_type)
 
 fetch mycursor into @the_id, @the_type
end
close mycursor
deallocate mycursor
go

-- verify results
select * from newTable
go
```